# Why do I have to run "bundle exec spring" when I have a bin/spring binstub?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring-gem

When running `spring` directly (without `bundle exec`) from the command line, nothing happens! Only when running `bundle exec spring`, it works:

```
$ spring status
$ bundle exec spring status
Spring is running:

21990 spring server | synaesthesia | started 1 min ago 
22046 spring app    | synaesthesia | started 43 secs ago | test mode
```

My `bin/spring` binstub looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# This file loads spring without using Bundler, in order to be fast
# It gets overwritten when you run the `spring binstub` command

unless defined?(Spring)
  require "rubygems"
  require "bundler"

  if match = Bundler.default_lockfile.read.match(/^GEM$.*?^    spring \((.*?)\)$.*?^$/m)
    ENV["GEM_PATH"] = ([Bundler.bundle_path.to_s] + Gem.path).join(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)
    ENV["GEM_HOME"] = ""
    Gem.paths = ENV

    gem "spring", match[1]
    require "spring/binstub"
  end
end
```

It has been patched by spring doing a `bundle exec spring binstub --all`. So I guess everything's configured correct? So why do I need a `bundle exec` all the time?

I'm using Rails 4.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I used a specific branch on github, so the REGEX created by spring in the `bin/spring` executable didn't match:

```
  if match = Bundler.default_lockfile.read.match(/^GEM$.*?^    spring \((.*?)\)$.*?^$/m)
```

I changed the line to the following:

if match = Bundler.default_lockfile.read.match(/^GEM|GIT$.*?^    spring ((.*?))$.*?^$/m)

Now it works. It's pretty strange though that there isn't at least some error thrown when the regex doesn't match?!

**Update**

I added an issue about this on the GitHub Spring project: https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/277